# ANSI-C constant-expression function like C++ constexpr?

Tags: c, c++11, constants, ansi-c

Putting it simple, is there an ANSI-C way of making a function a constant expression?

1. Pure ANSI-C but GNU extensions are acceptable - NO C++, though.
2. Preferably without relying on macros.
3. Something that surely behaives like the C++ `constexpr` and won't be solved at run time.

**Background:**

I need to implement a lot of math in an embedded processor that does not have floating point, so I am using fixed point in my application.

I don't like to see cryptic constants in my header files, though.
My hardware needs several floating-point constants (e.g. `130.7 microseconds`, `0.2503 mJ`) and I'd really like to be able to read (and change) my constants as the parts datasheet values are listed.

At a given moment, my hardware needs to use this constants, for example, to fill in a timer reload value, and, since the values are constant, i'd like to have somthing like:

```
// Header file.
static const int values_table[] =
{
    _Time( 123.45 ),    // 123.45 microseconds.
    // ...
};
```

And then:

```
// Application source file.

int conv_to_timer( x ) { /* my calculations - all const. */ }

// ...

void my_code( void )
{
    // ...
    timer_reload = conv_to_timer( values_table[ index ] );
```

One approach would be making my `_Time( x )` macro to do all calculations needed for the timer values but it is not flexible (i.e. not comparable against someting outside) neither portable (a different hardware would demand a different calculation).

Any suggestions for an elegant approach, please?

Comment: I'm not quite following your objections to using macros.  In particular, what prevents the expansion of a macro from being compared to "something outside"?  Are you talking about the fact that it has no linkage?  And how is a function any better than a macro if different hardware needs a different computation?

Comment: No.  `constexpr` is an extra feature in C++ not in (standard) C — there isn't anything analogous.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @JohnBollinger. The point with macros is that it has to be in the same place as I declare my constants while a function can be in a different translation unit, and thus, not tainting the header file with an application specific purpose. Did I manage to explain?

Comment: Why wouldn't you simply use a #DEFINE for the value or as a macro?

Comment: What I would do to avoid that is use macros and put them either directly in an implementation file (`*.c`) or, if multiple files need the macros, put the macros in a header file but store the header together with the `*.c` files, not in the actual `include` directory. You would include the file using ``#include "..."` then, not `#include <...>`.

Comment: Hello @DavidHoelzer. For the reason I explained in the comment above. I would like to keep my hardware peripheral constants decoupled from the application. Of course I can `#define` a conversion macro in my application sources or provide a "mutant" macro set... many possibilities and I humbly ask for community insights to reach an optimal solution. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Downvoter (and please don't downvote me despite my stupidity). I think it is the "standard way of doing". I was just wondering whether could I find any better solution. I am used to C++ where I have `constexpr` and template metaprogramming aids.

Comment: An out-of-the-box idea, if you insist on avoiding macros, could be to define your own "toy language" to define stuff and then just generate the best C code for your platform.

Comment: Rather than `_Time( 123.45 ), // 123.45 microseconds.`, consider a macro `ns_TO_RELOAD(123450),` and drop FP, drop comments when code should be self-explanatory.

Comment: Thanks @chux. I don't really need to drop the FP if macros (or whathever) can handle it at compile time. This way my values will look exactly as in datasheet. Ok, I can rename `_Time()` macro to `_us()` or `_Time_us()` to make it clearer. Physical dimension _and_ unit.

Comment: @j4x A value in dropping FP is that macro math does not work well, if at all, at macro translation time.  Further, by using integer math, the conversion to `reload` units can be precisely controlled without rounding and other FP concerns.  Like `#define ns_TO_RELOAD(ns) (((ns) + TICKS_PER_ns/2)/TICKS_PER_ns - 1)`

Comment: There's always the option of having a pre-compilation step to preprocess the source code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TL;DR: use macros.

Standard C does not have a direct analog of C++'s `constexpr`.  The closest things are macros and inline functions, and of those two, macros can be used in some ways that inline functions cannot be used -- in particular, inline functions cannot be used where C requires a constant expression (hmmm ... sounds similar to any C++ keyword you know?), but macros, on the other hand, can expand to suitable expressions.

`constexpr` was introduced into C++ largely to provide an alternative to macros where a non-trivial but compile-time-computable expression is required.  I believe they also have some advantages, such as with respect to the types of values that they can cause to be computed at compile time, but those seem not relevant to your particular case.  In C, where `constexpr` was never introduced, macros are still the standard way to go.

Your primary objection to using macros seems to be essentially about code style.  You observe that the body of a C++ `constexpr` function can be in a different translation unit than the "calls" to it, and that is apparently attractive to you.  Do note, however, that if that were an option for you then you would still need at least *declarations* of such functions in the translation units that used them, so you'd not actually saving very much in terms of cleanliness.  Furthermore, although each translation unit must contain the body of each macro it uses, you can still segregate the macro definitions into a separate header.

Overall, then, I don't see that avoiding macros -- if you could -- would really gain you anything.  I'm inclined to think that the C++ community's general aversion to macros was as big a motivation for `constexpr` as any functional benefit.  If it happens that you are afflicted by that particular aversion then you really need to get over it to program effectively in standard C.

Comment: Thanks again @JohnBollinger. I don't plan to bring any discussion about "macro illness" and I think your response is actually the only way out. I must comment, though, about the difficulty of nailing down macro cluttered code. Compiler messages get bloated, type safety goes away and the maintainance tends to be harder. Well... is life...

Comment: @John Bollinger even macros are not a direct replacement just one example: `constexpr int f(int number)
{
    return number == 1? 1 : (number * f(nnumber - 1));
}` it is difficult to imagine the macro ot inline function with the same functionality. So f(10) will be calculated compile time and f(variable) run time or c++14 iteration verison `constexpr int f(int n)
{
 int result = 1;
    for(int i = 2 ; i <= n; i++) result *= i;
    return result;
}`

Comment: @PeterJ, I acknowledge that `constexpr` functions can do things that macros cannot, but that's beside the point because they are not an option for the OP.  However, I have tweaked the answer wording slightly to be less restrictive about the nature of the things that it says a `constexpr` function can do.

Answer (score 2):

Trust your optimizer, then verify.

C++ `constexpr` was designed based on optimizations that compilers already do. If you write:

```
int fac( int n ) {
  int r = 1;
  for (int i = 2; i < n; ++i)
    r*=i;
  return r;
}
```

then do

```
printf("%d", fac(10));
```

the compiler under modest optimization settings will evaluate the call to `fac` and replace the call with the constant return value of `fac(10)`.

`constexpr` mostly exists to permit `fac(10)` to be used in semantically constant places, like the size of an array in C++.  So in C++ you can do:

```
char buffer[fac(10)];
```

if and only if `fac(10)` is `constexpr`.  (C has variable sized arrays).

You can write `_Time` as a macro, or you could write it as an `inline` function and tell your compiler to optimize.  Then check the resulting binary to see if it has stored the array with the final values.

A macro could also be used, but macros have the usual debugging problems (I am unaware of a compiler that gives you decent step-through of macros when they screw up) which make them less suitable for complex code.

Understand that C++ gives you zero guarantees that a `constexpr` function is actually evaluated at compile time.  It simply permits you to use it in additional contexts, and most compilers will precompute it for you.